# Node Inspector not exploding object properties

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-inspector

from yesterday I'm facing a strange behavior with `grunt-node-inspector`.

As I debug my app, I was used to set breakpoint and watch expression, then if my watched variable is an Array or a Object I could click on the grey arrow to see the properties (or the elements in the array). Now If I click on that arrow, simply nothing is happening...

[image]

I've not updated anything, so I can't understand why the inspector start behaving like this.

`node` version is: `v0.10.31` 
`grunt-node-inspector` is `0.1.5`
`node-inspector`is `0.7.4`

Any Idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I've just updated node-inspector from `0.7.4` to `0.8.3` using the npm update command and it is now fixed.

To check what global packages can be updated run `npm -g outdated`. A list of outdated global packages will be shown.
Run `npm update -g node-inspector` if it is shown as needing an update.

If it doesn't show in the list of global outdated packages you may have installed it locally to your project.

Navigate to your project directory that contains the package.json file.
Run the same commands as above but do not include the `-g` flag.

This should update node-inspector and fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot... updating global node-inspector works for me, not it complains that I'm still running on `0.10.x` but i can survive to that!